# For Each loop to execute two array value in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Need to Pass two array value to MySQL database to insert the array values.
I am posting the array values from form:

```
<input type='checkbox' name=ticket[] value=".$TicketNo.">
<input type='hidden' name=cpt[] value=".$cpt.">
```

And pass the form value into database by:

```
 foreach($_POST['ticket'] as $ticket && $_POST['cpt'] as $cpt )
 {

 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT  arlog SET assdate='$assdate',TicketNo='$ticket',assign='$assign',status='New',quality_status='New',provider='$provider',cpt='$cpt'")
 or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

I know `mysql_query` is not being used widely, but as a newbee I am using it. So just ignore the statement and guide me for using for each loop to pass two array values. By passing only the ticket number it works fine but I want to pass the cpt too.

Comment: either use a multipleIterator or use the key on the other post array on another one. do note that if you got a mismatch it'll spew an undefined index error. or much better to create a grouping name index on the form

Comment: So you gave up or what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver. Thank you for your answer. I have used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to ignore the `mysql_*` as you need to move to MySQLi or PDO as you know.  But use the key from `$_POST['ticket']` to access `$_POST['cpt']`:

```
foreach($_POST['ticket'] as $key => $ticket)
{
    $cpt = $_POST['cpt'][$key];
}
```

It is better to specify the array keys, especial since checkboxes won't be submitted if not checked:

```
<input type='checkbox' name=ticket[0] value=".$TicketNo.">
<input type='hidden' name=cpt[0] value=".$cpt.">

<input type='checkbox' name=ticket[1] value=".$TicketNo.">
<input type='hidden' name=cpt[1] value=".$cpt.">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set array of array like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name=ticket[][number] value=".$TicketNo.">
<input type='hidden' name=ticket[][cpt] value=".$cpt.">
```

And concatenate one sql query with each two field names like single:

```
$inserts = array();
foreach ($_POST['ticket'] as $ticket) {
    $inserts[] = "'{$ticket['number']}', '{$ticket['cpt']}'";
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl (TicketNo, cpt) VALUES (' . join('),(', $inserts) . ');';
```